# Will searching SPWebApplication.Sites with Linq need to be diposed?

Tags: linq, dispose

Situation: I only have the full URL of an image in our farm & no knowledge of where it comes from other than being in the web application so I need to locate the site/web/list/item segments.

Since I will already know the WebApplication this is my function

```
 public string GetSiteUrl(SPWebApplication webapp, string FullUrl){
      return result = webapp.Sites.Where( s=>FullUrl.Contains(s.Url)).Select(s => s.url).OrderByDescending( s => s.length).First())
 }
```

assuming it is the valid url for an image, 'results' will contain my URL, but does this cause a memory leak since **webapp.Sites** is enumerated but not disposed ?

I also then intend to use a similar Linq query to get the SPWeb Url from SPSite.AllWebs

Comment: I just wouldn't use Linq :) http://blog.furuknap.net/why-linq-to-sharepoint-is-a-bad-idea You can write the equivalent of that in like 10 lines and not have to worry about whether or not the objects are being disposed.

Comment: I felt this way for a long time but I did some comparisons for sorting time between Linq & custom sorts; Linq was such an improved speed I started to have more faith, a little to much as it would seem. Thanks for the article, great read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will instantiate every SPSite in the web application which will cause two problems:

1. It'll be very slow if you have many Site collections in the Web Application
2. It'll leak memory unless you dispose all of the SPSites.

This implementation will be a lot faster and won't leak:

```
public string GetSiteUrl(SPWebApplication webapp, string FullUrl) {
  using (var site = new SPSite(FullUrl))
  {
    return site.FullUrl;
  }
}
```

Just calling the SPSite constructor with a Url of something in SharePoint will give you back the best matching Site Collection, if you then use `site.OpenWeb()` you'll get the best matching Site.

Comment: Very glad to know it does leak. I had tested this approach in PowerShell, it did not work there I assumed it would fail in C# as well. I was wrong. Thanks!